# How to debug Java cryptography extensions?

Tags: bouncycastle, jce

I am implementing an encryption algorithm with a product. I would like to understand how bouncy castle handles the defaults like Initialization vector and so on. But I am not able to get any breakpoint working in intellij, I think it has got something to do with JCE provider.

Comment: And are you using the *debug* version of the Bouncycastle provider?

Comment: No. I am using the one provided by maven repo. I will try to use the debug version. Thanks